# Python multiprocessing between ubuntu and centOS

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run some parallel jobs through Python multiprocessing. Here is an example code:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def f(name, total):
    print('process {:d} starting doing business in {:d}'.format(name, total))
    #there will be some unix command to run external program


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_task_num = 100
    mp.Queue()
    all_processes = []
    for i in range(total_task_num):
        p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(i,total_task_num))
        all_processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in all_processes:
        p.join()
```

I also set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` to make sure that only one thread for one process.

Now I have 20 cores in my desktop. For 100 parallel jobs, I want to let it run 5 cycles so that each core run one job (20*5=100).

I tried to do the same code in CentOS and ubuntu. It seems that CentOS will automatically do a job splitting. In other words, there will be only 20 parallel running jobs at the same time. However, ubuntu will start 100 jobs simultaneously. As such, each core will be occupied by 5 jobs. This will significantly increase the total run time due to high work load.

I wonder if there is an elegant solution to teach ubuntu to run only 1 job per core.

Answer (score 1):

To enable a process run on a specific CPU, you use the command taskset in linux. Accordingly you can arrive on a logic based on "taskset -p [mask] [pid]" that assigns each process to a specific core in a loop.

Also , python helps in incorporation of affinity control via sched_setaffinity that can be checked for confining a process to specific cores. Accordingly , you can arrive on a logic for usage of "os.sched_setaffinity(pid, mask)" where pid is the process id of the process whose mask represents the group of CPUs to which the process shall be confined to.

In python, there are also other tools like https://pypi.org/project/affinity/ that can be explored for usage.